# what is the error of cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition in selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests

I have wrritten a feature file to test the create elements button. But it generates an error message of

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition.
```

I dont know why its happening since I am new to automation testing.

The following is the code that I have written.

```
@When("^create elements$")
public void create_elements_for_attributes(WebElement elementToClick) throws Throwable {
driver.findElement(By.id("newElement")).click();
}
```

The error that I have recieved is as follows.

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'mCollector.features.StepDefinitions_mCollector.create_elements_for_attributes(WebElement) in file:/C:/Users/Admin/workspace/MStudio%20-%20eBilling/bin/' with pattern [^create elements$] is declared with 1 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments [].
```

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition" in java testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68890409/what-is-cucumber-runtime-cucumberexception-arity-mismatch-step-definition-in)

Answer (score 7):

In your `create_elements_for_attributes` method you are expecting one argument of type `WebElement` but your regex does not capture any arguments. It should look something like that instead:

```
@When("^create elements \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

And then in your feature file:

```
When create elements "element"
```

But that won't work either because you can't pass a `WebeElement` object from your Cucumber feature file. You should only operate with primitive values and DataTables. Other types (like `WebeElement)` should be created internally in the glue code itself.